# How are switches for two monitors called? Or can I use a monitor split?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I have 2 monitors, 1 desktop and 1 laptop. I would like to switch the display between desktop and laptop and want to use 2 monitors as extended monitor sources.
I see  there are lot of solutions to switch between 1 monitor sharing 2 sources but not for 2 monitors.

How about this? I will go with a switch that facilitates 2 sources 1 monitor, but I will attach a split to the switch and connect to the 2 monitors... is that going to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to look for **Dual Monitor KVM** switches, which should get you what you want.

Don't use the term `switch` as it is way to broad and will also result in other type of products unrelated to what you are after. **`KVM`** stands for Keyboard, Video & Mouse which is a specific property of the switch you are looking for. To denote that a KVM switch supports multiple monitors, use `Dual Monitor`.

Splitting could also work.